# gracefully stopping Apache Solr from command line

Tags: solr, jetty, java

I using using jetty to run Solr using the following cmd line:
java -jar start.jar &

how can I stop this instance of solr gracefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the process id with `ps` and send it a signal to stop using `kill` - I believe the `HUP` or `INT` signals will allow the java process to gracefully exit; test to confirm.

Better yet, you should really be using a proper service to run Solr - Tomcat can do this, or Jetty can be made to run as a service.

Comment: I currently use ps and kill with HUP. I was hoping for a more elegant way, where I don't have to lookup the process ID and then send the kill HUP.

Comment: @SaqibAli The elegant way to do it would be to set it up as a service via an init script - either by using a servlet engine like Tomcat that comes set up for that, or by setting one up for your Jetty process.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the previous answer, in the command:

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=8001 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar
```

The `-DSTOP.PORT=port` should specify an *available* port (different from the port configured in the `solr_home/etc/jetty.xml` used for Jetty). I tried in the next way to start it:

```
nohup java -DSTOP.PORT=8001 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar &
```

And just added the `--stop` parameter to stop it:

```
nohup java -DSTOP.PORT=8001 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar --stop &
```

In both cases is working fine but still it doesn't look gracefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Start it (defining stop.port and stop.key variables):

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=8080 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar
```

then you can stop it:

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=8080 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar --stop
```

[source](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/07/26/jetty-stop-a-jetty-server-by-command/#comment-66161)